# If i rotate a shape over a tangent line does this act maintain the fundamental group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I don't know if this is true or not. If I rotate a shape 360 degrees over a tangent line, does this act maintain the fundamental group ($\pi_1$)?

For example, I get a ruined doughnut from $S^1$.

I tried it for some easy problems and it was working. (Sorry if this is a very bad question, but I couldn't prove or find a counterexample for it...)

Comment: How do you rotate over a line? A rotation has a center which is a point. Do you mean any rotation of center an intersection point of a tangent line and the shape? (Maybe I misunderstood the problem)

Comment: Yes, i take the intersection as the center of rotation